# H-bridge acting strange

Tags: microcontroller, h-bridge

I am making a robot with two coin batteries rated at 3V and using ATMega164 microcontroller. I am trying to run the motors in both directions for which I am using an h-bridge. I need it to be surface mount so I ordered 'LA6585FA-BH'. I connected its IN+ and IN- inputs to OCR0A and OCR0B pins on the micro, the OUT terminals connected to the motor and CT connected to ground.

While I was testing this h-bridge I noticed that the motor goes in one direction but in the other direction it wouldn't. So when OCR0A = 0 and OCR0B = 255 the motor works but when the values are the other way around it wouldn't work. Also, I noticed that when the power (Vcc pin) is cut while everything else is connected, the motor still vibrates but very little. Shouldn't the motor be completely switched off when Vcc is unplugged?

Do these h-bridges usually work like this or is it something that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why did you hook CT to ground without the recommended cap? What are these OCRoX that can apparently range from 0 to 255? Why are you using an H bridge that expects a hall fx sensor while you just want to control your [I suppose brushed DC] motor with the micro?

Comment: I think a link to the data sheet would be nice.

Comment: @VladimirCravero, At first I had the recommended cap on CT but the motor would just pulsate like a servo but wouldn't stay on continuously. OCR0A and OCR0B are the 8-bit PWM pins of the microcontroller. The motors are coin motors 3mm in size. Very tiny and takes about 100mA of current at full speed (according to its datasheet)

Answer (score 1):

The LA6585 is designed for use with linear Hall effect sensors which have an output voltage swing of less than 1V. The datasheet doesn't say what voltage range the inputs can handle, but I suspect that they don't like being driven to the supply rails. You could try reducing the voltage swing using three equal value (1k~10k) resistors on each input - one resistor to Vcc, one to GND, and the other going to the MCU output. This will reduce the voltage swing on each input to 1/3 Vcc (centered at 1/2 Vcc).

If you remove Vcc from the LA6585 but leave everything else connected then it could still be powered through its inputs, perhaps via ESD diodes which are internally connected between the inputs and Vcc. Putting high value resistors in the signal lines will reduce this stray current to a low level, and should prevent the motor from vibrating.